# Unable to persist entity with @OneToMany Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is the entity parent child relationship

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class ConcurrencySafeEntity  {
  @Id
  String id;
}
```

Parent entity

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Label extends ConcurrencySafeEntity {

    //Child
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "label")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    private Set<Forecasted> shipments;
}
```

Child Entity hierarchy

Inheritance Super class

```
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Super extends ConcurrencySafeEntity implements Comparable<Super> {
  ...
}
```

Child class

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Forecasted extends Super  {

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "forecast_label")
    private Label label;
}
```

Spring Data Repository

```
public interface ForecastLabelRepository extends JpaRepository<Label, String>,
        GenericRepository<Label, String> {
}

@Repository
public interface GenericRepository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> S save(S var1);

    <S extends T> Iterable<S> save(Iterable<S> var1);

    T findOne(ID var1);

}
```

All the above code is bootstrapped with the below service method

```
@Transactional(timeout = 60)
    public void run(Label label) {

        Set<Forecasted> shipments = service
                .forecast(
                        label
                );

        label.addForecasts(shipments);

        labelRepository.save(label);
    }
```

Now when I execute I get the below error, that it is unable to save Label because it cannot find Forecast, which I feel should be cascaded automatically, tried persisting the Forecast too, but obviously fails with Label not found, below is the stack trace snippet

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.models.forcasting.management.Forecasted with id 09f7f2ae-4ffe-41e4-bdaf-4d833d1467d8; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find xxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.xxxxx.models.forcasting.management.Forecasted with id 09f7f2ae-4ffe-41e4-bdaf-4d833d1467d8
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:389)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.save(Unknown Source)
```